# Bullet Collision Shape doesn't wrap Model correctly

Tags: android, libgdx

i got an object called `human` and an object called `platform`.

I simply let the human fall down on the platform with a constant speed. No acceleration!

The problem is that my collision shapes for both (i use `btBoxShape` to keep it simple) objects are not wrapping the associated object accordingly:

[image]
i scaled it up in paint, sorry for the bad resolution

I got this result calculating the bounds for the `model`, retrieve the `dimensions` and the `center` and then i create a `btBoxShape` with half of the `dimensions` and add it to the `collisionObject`:

```
box = new BoundingBox();
this.calculateBoundingBox(box);
box.getCenter(center);
box.getDimensions(dimensions);
collisionObject = new btCollisionObject();
boxShape = new btBoxShape(dimensions.sub(dimensions.x/2f, dimensions.y/2f, dimensions.z/2f));
collisionObject.setCollisionShape(boxShape);
```

And then i set the `worldTransforms` of the `collisionObject` to the transform of the object to be drawn(for instance human):

```
instances.get(0).collisionObject.setWorldTransform(instances.get(0).transform);
```

So how can i make the `collisionShape` wrap `model`?

This is the `human` in `Blender`:

[image]

I appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nobody an idea how to fit the collision shapes to the models?